# Data Science Podcasts?

Tags: reference-request

What are some podcasts which are related to data science?

This is a similar question to the [reference request question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/927/statistical-podcasts).

Details/rules:

- The podcasts (the theme and the episodes) should be related to data science. (For example: A podcast which is about some other domain, with an episode which speaks about data science in that domain, is not a good reference/answer.)
- Personal opinions/reviews (if any) would be very helpful too.

Comment: Many of the podcasts mentioned in the answers are no longer active. A dynamic list is present here - https://dspods.netlify.app/. It's a helpful resource for anyone looking for some interesting data science podcast. Disclaimer: I am the creator of this website.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I strongly suggest [Talking Machines](http://www.thetalkingmachines.com). It's a very well put together podcast from a professor at Harvard. They cater to both machine learning experts and enthusiasts.

Their interviews are often done from NIPS, and the guests are usually top tier practitioners.

Comment: (+1) Thanks!  That's a nice one.  Heard a couple from that podcast.  I would vouch for their quality.

Answer (score 6):

In [**Data Skeptic**](http://dataskeptic.com/) they talk about different aspects of data science:

> Data Skeptic is a podcast that alternates between short mini episodes with the host explaining concepts from data science to his non-data scientist wife, and longer interviews featuring practitioners and experts on interesting topics related to data, all through the eye of scientific skepticism.

This is a good intro to Data Science which also explains the basic concepts in a not too technical way.

---

A bit more technical is [**Partially Derivative**](http://www.partiallyderivative.com/):

> Partially Derivative is a podcast about the data of everything. Each week we look at a new way that data has changed how we understand and experience the world. From ancient warfare to modern love and everything in between.

---

A related Quora question: [What are the best data science podcasts?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-data-science-podcasts)

Answer (score 4):

Some which I regularly hear to, are:

- [What's the point](http://fivethirtyeight.com/tag/whats-the-point/) by FiveThirtyEight

It is a very nice podcast, where not only the concepts, but also the applications of data science to a wide range of domains, are discussed.

- [Linear digressions](https://www.udacity.com/podcasts/linear-digressions) by Udacity

It focuses more on ML and concepts of data science. Hosted by two really nice data scientists Katie and Ben.  All their episodes are fun to watch.

- Partially Derivative  (Already mentioned by agold)
- Data Skeptic  (Already mentioned by agold)
- Talking Machine  (Already mentioned by jamesmf)
- [Freakonomics](http://freakonomics.com/radio/freakonomics-radio-podcast-archive/)

It is a fun podcast which focuses on data and it's importance in various domains and how to make sense of it.

Comment: What's the Point is great.

Answer (score 2):

[Not So Standard Deviations](https://soundcloud.com/nssd-podcast) by Hilary Parker and Roger Peng! Fun little podcast where they talk about a variety of things. They only have 4 episodes out currently, but they seem to be releasing one every two weeks, so there's that.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other podcasts not mentioned previously:

- [OCDQ](http://www.ocdqblog.com/podcast/): for some interesting discussions on data quality and Big Data.
- [Learning Machine 101](http://www.learningmachines101.com/): for begginer level discussion on machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

[The R-Podcast](http://www.r-podcast.org/) is a podcast about data analysis in R. Other cases are [O'Reilly Data Show](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/oreilly-data-show/id944929220?intcmp=il-data-na-na-na_20150826_radar_data_show_podcast_post_top_subscribe_cta) and [O'Reilly Radar Podcasts](http://radar.oreilly.com/tag/podcast)

Answer (score 0):

**Data Skeptic** has become one of the best information science podcasts as well as a resource for such a fresh take on science, data-driven analysis, and scepticism on a wide range of issues, including large datasets, machine learning, statistics, and data science in general.

This is a podcast that comes out every week. It implies that now the blog publishes data-science-related programmes and blogs virtually weekly so that listeners can get a clear view of the world of information. There are a total of 277 episodes.